# export table data from oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I need to create a flat file in java. In this flat file i write the insert statement where data comes from oracle table.
Following is my java code

```
stmtSQL="SELECT * FROM Table1";
resultSQL=null;
resultSQL=myCreateStmt.executeQuery(stmtSQL);
strSQLIns="";
while(resultSQL.next())
{
strSQLIns=strSQLIns+"INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('";
for(int iLoopCtr=0;iLoopCtr<27;iLoopCtr++)
{
    if(iLoopCtr==26)
        strSQLIns=strSQLIns+resultSQL.getString(iLoopCtr+1)+"'";
    else
        strSQLIns=strSQLIns+resultSQL.getString(iLoopCtr+1)+"','";
}
strSQLIns=strSQLIns+");\n";
}
```

when I run this code system generates the insert statement like this

```
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('80896948       ','gMWcjDMPXox4LVyrXGw0Ok+4SQI=');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('39454249       ','z+5fkcA+7wrZrF2455kngiTdYU4=');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('52167960       ','+N55nru+ewwhKPJygW99T8yEQXg=');
```

Now I do not want to use to while loop so code generate the above insert statement. I want some quick way so i generate such formatted sql query.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (c1,c2) (SELECT '1', 'first row' FROM dual  UNION SELECT '2', 'second    row' FROM dual);
```

Comment: Is there any way to bring table's data in the formatted way in a single run like this "INSERT INTO Table1 (c1,c2) (SELECT '1', 'first row' FROM dual  UNION SELECT '2', 'second    row' FROM dual);" so we can insert multiple row with single insert statement.

Comment: @prem did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a production environment: the quickest way to do what you need is to use the import/export tools Oracle gives you

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch01.htm

If you have an academic problem or are doing this for the sake of it:

Your program is a nice point to start with.  I would read the `ResultSetMetadata`, so you can drop that magic '26' from your code.  Just store it all in a `List<String[]>` and then build your INSERT-SELECT command by iterating on that list.  Beware that the example is over-simplified, and you will run with some problems:

- With some data types as dates and numbers, you will have to be extra-careful to format them as correct strings
- With some data types as BLOB, your idea is not likely to work

Comment: I am working in a production environment data. My code will generate the long list of insert statement as shown in the example but i want, is there any way to create formatted single insert statement with multiple rows from table in oracle. the expected example is shown in the second list. When the file is created then this data will be uploaded on other db to work remotely